# Bootstrap 4 "All" tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have created toggleable tabs using Bootstrap 4 "tablist", they are toggleable and work great.

I want to create an "All" tab that will show all of the content of all the different tabs and can't figure out how to make an "All" tab work!
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here are my tab headings:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#cases">Cases</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#revrul">Rev. Rul.s & Notices</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#regs">Regulations</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="cases" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>Cases</h3>
      <ul> Content for cases here</ul>
    </div>
    <div id="revrul" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Rev. Rul.s &amp; Notices</h3>
      <ul> Content for rulings here</ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="regs" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
    <h3>Regulations</h3>
    <ul> Content for regulations here </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what doesn't work? Hard to debug a problem where you have given a working example, but not including the troubling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to manually add some JS that controls the behavior of the "All" link.

What you want to do is:

- Create a special tab for showing all content, with ID #show_all
- When you click this tab, it adds classes .active and .show to all the panes, so that they'll all be visible.
- When you click on a tab that does not have the #show_all ID, it removes the classes .show and .active from all the tab panes that are not the one that you're looking for.

Here's a working snippet.

```js
$("#show_all").on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass("active").parent("li").siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");
  $(".tab-pane").removeClass("fade").addClass("active").addClass("show");
});
$(".nav-link").not("#show_all").on("click", function() {
  console.log(this.hash);
  $(".tab-pane").not(this.hash).removeClass("active").removeClass("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#cases">Cases</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#revrul">Rev. Rul.s & Notices</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#regs">Regulations</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#" id="show_all">All</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="cases" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
    <h3>Cases</h3>
    <ul> Content for cases here</ul>
  </div>
  <div id="revrul" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
    <h3>Rev. Rul.s & Notices</h3>
    <ul> Content for rulings here</ul>
  </div>
  <div id="regs" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
    <h3>Regulations</h3>
    <ul> Content for regulations here </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$( ".tabContent" ).clone().appendTo("#tabContent");
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#all">All</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#cases">Cases</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#revrul">Rev. Rul.s & Notices</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#regs">Regulations</a></li>
</ul>
  
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="all" class="container tab-pane active">
        <h3>ALL</h3>
        <div id="tabContent">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cases" class="container tab-pane active">
        <div class="tabContent">
            <h3>Cases</h3>
            <ul> Content for cases here</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="revrul" class="container tab-pane fade">
        <div class="tabContent">
            <h3>Rev. Rul.s & Notices</h3>
            <ul> Content for rulings here</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="regs" class="container tab-pane fade">
        <div class="tabContent">
            <h3>Regulations</h3>
            <ul> Content for regulations here </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```